# How to ask a question across multiple Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, superuser, serverfault, askubuntu

How do you ask a question on Ask Ubuntu, Server Fault, the Unix and Linux SE, and Super User all at once?  My [particular question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176287/connection-refused-on-localhost-25-apache-james) is about Ubuntu so I put it there, but it could easily fit at any of the others.

Comment: You don't. Ask your question on the most appropriate site.

Comment: You should either ask how to do something, or ask for a feature request to be able to do something that you currently can't.  Based on your tags, you know that this can't be done.  The text of your question should be in line with that.

Comment: @Bart I did add the feature-request tag...I would like such functionality.

Comment: Fair enough, but I fear the answer will be "not gonna happen". Cross-posting is a bad bad thing and should not be done. You're better off taking the advice you've been given in the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple answer: **Don't.**

The more detailed answer:   Each SE has a specific set of FAQ and guidelines that specify what kind of questions may be appropriate there, and yes, there's a lot of overlap between the different SE sites.  Your example is likely a usage issue of Apache on Ubuntu, so my gut feeling tells me that asking the question on Ask Ubuntu would be better than spreading it out everywhere.

This also encourages you to have a narrow scope with your question.  This improves the quality and usefulness of the question, and has an effect on the answers, too.

Comment: why can't you  check a box for "also, put this on unix and linux"?

Comment: You should be specific with the scope of your question.  Do you want an answer that pertains to Ubuntu, Apache, or a use of Apache with Ubuntu?  From here you select which SE you want to ask your question on.

Answer (score 4):

You should choose the Stack Exchange site where you think your question has more chance to get an answer between those sites where the question is on-topic.

If the question is about different aspects, for which a different Stack Exchange is appropriate, then you should split the question in different questions you ask in different Stack Exchange sites. You should not ask the same exact question on different sites, but rather tailor the question for the site where you are asking it.