# The "on-topic paradox"

Tags: discussion

Imagine I have a question that's on-topic on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

I want to get useful answers from experts and people who know the solution to my question.

I choose one of those multiple sites, and I post my question on there.

Crossposting isn't allowed, so I lose out on the expertise of the second site's users.

In other words, this describes the questions that:

1. It is a bit unclear which site on the Stack Exchange network those questions theoretically fit on.
2. The total number of such questions is large enough such that having on ask on a meta site each time is **not** an ideal solution.
3. The core of the question is on-topic on multiple Stack Exchange sites in a way such that it is very difficult to modify the question to fit only a single site.

How do I resolve such a situation?

Comment: Related question: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in). I think it's a good guide, and a lot of [site-recommendation] questions get closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: We can fix them by realising you're trying to create a problem that doesn't exist enough to worry about creating arcane rules that are ignored where new users then launch into Meta about some hypothetical situation of a handful of minor questions

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230636/am-i-encouraged-to-ask-my-question-on-multiple-se-qa-sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143683/how-to-ask-a-question-across-multiple-stack-exchange-sites  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215512/where-should-i-post-my-question-when-it-overlaps-multiple-sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207856/where-to-post-if-questions-fit-multiple-networks

Comment: @random You're sort of disproving your own claim of "doesn't exist"

Comment: Those others are better formed attempts at this non-issue whereas this question fails to leg up

Comment: @random, It seems to be enough of an issue that multiple, *repeated* questions have been asked about it.

Comment: @Downvoters, mind explaning?

Comment: Your question is unclear and shows no research effort

Comment: My question seems quite clear,  and also that's not a funny joke. As for research effort, dozens of Meta questions already exist about this, read them instead of just calling it a "non-issue".

Comment: Nowhere in your post have you shown that you know how to use the site search. If dozens of other posts exist why have you not mentioned them or posted under those?

Comment: @random Now you know, it's much bigger than the "non-issue" you previously claimed it is.

Comment: Did you read any of the other links or do you think they're there for decoration?

Comment: TheBitByte, you completely changed the question with your edit. I rolled back the post to undo it.

Comment: @HDE 226868 It's kind of the same question, but worded quite a bit better.

Comment: If your question is on-topic on multiple sites, then you haven't narrowed the problem sufficiently to post it on *any* site.  Work on it some more, until you narrow it down to the point it's only on-topic on one site.

Comment: @Fbueckert If the core of a question is indeed on-topic for multiple sites, then the issue seems partly with the sites' scopes, not just the question.

Comment: No, it means you haven't narrowed the problem sufficiently.  If it's on-topic on multiple sites, then you have to figure out where the problem really lies; is it in a specific expertise, like programming?  Or is it in a different area?  Being on-topic on multiple sites is a hallmark of a fairly vague question.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's just me, but I feel there really aren't many cases where a question could conceivably be on-topic on a bunch of Stack Exchange sites. Yes, that can be the case for a programming question - especially for those of us (myself included) who have little experience with programming or the programming sites - but in that case, there's [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/274942) to help you out.

Many of the non-programming sites are very different. Sure, there are possible overlaps:

- English Language & Usage/English Language Learners
- Physics/Astronomy and Physics/Chemistry
- Biology/Health
- Mathematics/Math Overflow
- Science Fiction & Fantasy/Movies & TV
- History of Science & Mathematics/History and HSM/Generic science or mathematics site

There are probably others, given the number of migrations we have, but the amount of cases where a question is likely very on-topic on multiple sites is not high.

If you have a question which could potentially require expertise from, say, Seasoned Advice, Physics, and Science Fiction & Fantasy, perhaps it's a bit too broad. Stack Exchange is suitable for *focused, specific questions*. Questions that cover a wide range of topics are likely not good.

---

Let's say that I'm wrong about all of the above, and that such questions do exist, overlapping with sites A and B. My suggestion is to ask on the meta of site A or site B - maybe both, come to think of it - and ask whether the site feels the questions should be on-topic or off-topic. Ideally, the question should include

- Real examples of such questions and/or examples you thought of.
- An argument for why the questions should be on-topic/off-topic, if you have a position.
- A suggestion for placing a short blurb about the result in the help center and/or tour of the site, if it's a major issue; this might prevent more of these questions from coming on the site.

Answer will hopefully have

- A suggestion as to whether or not the posts should be on-topic of off-topic, and reasoning to support the above conclusion.
- Maybe a suggestion of the phrasing for the help/center or tour.

The point of this meta posts - or posts, if done on multiple sites - is to have an official place to point people to if they ask questions in the future or ask if they can ask such questions.

Comment: @TheBitByte Indeed, which is why I suggested asking just *one* meta question about the entire class of questions.

Comment: @TheBitByte No, I mean one meta question on each of the metas of the sites where the specific class of questions on problematic.

Comment: @TheBitByte Why is it temporary? You permanently decide whether to allow the questions or not.

Comment: @TheBitByte I'm still confused. You'd be resolving the scope problem by coming to a consensus using the meta post.

Comment: And then you'd do this for each and every affected class of questions, which is not an efficient solution.

Comment: @TheBitByte I'm not at all convinced that there are as many "affected classes of questions" as you claim there are. I'm still not convinced there's a problem that needs a solution.

Comment: I don't know how much there are, but what's more important is the general idea behind this, not how many questions it exists in. It's like saying sometimes dealing with spam is not important because the amount of spam hasn't increased yet.

Comment: Correct. If there's no spam, don't fight spam. Wait until there's spam to fight spam. Fighting spam that doesn't exist is "not an efficient solution" as you put it.

Comment: @Clive You seem to have misunderstood. I was saying that prevention is better than cure.

Comment: @DanBron Let's not resort to strawmans, shall we?

Comment: @TheBitByte How can an independent third party determine whether the issue you want to get ahead of is realistic enough to warrant the energy to solve it in advance? I could imagine any number of potential risks which we could face, all of them you'd find hard to label "straw men", but nonetheless none of them are material or pressing today. So how can we decide whether a given non-present risk, whether yours or one I invent, is sufficiently imminent to pull resources from building the other features we're currently waiting on?

Comment: @TheBitByte Pragmatically, that sounds like evasion.

Comment: @TheBitByte Maybe try reading it? It was a third attempt to get you to clarify the value of solving a problem which hasn't manifested yet. It was long because you haven't responded to the first two shorter attempts, and I didn't want to be accused of rhetoric again (though I was, again).

Comment: @DanBron That was  a bit rude....

Comment: @TheBitByte ... and again. Do you want to try answering the question, or would you rather keep impugning my character?

Comment: @DanBron ?? ...

Comment: @TheBitByte I'll take that as "no, I am not interested in clarifying the value of my feature request", then. At least you forebode from insulting me this time, that's an improvement.

Comment: @DanBron What? My question has no [tag:feature-request] tag...

Comment: @TheBitByte My cat doesn't have a tattoo that says "I am a cat", either, but he's still a cat. This question doesn't have the feature-request tag, but it's still a feature request. Now, disregarding that yet further evasive distraction: do you have any interest in clarifying the value of solving a problem which by your own admission has not yet manifested, vs the other things we can spend that time, effort, and money on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm mod on a couple of sites where this can happen (e.g. Security has some overlap with Crypto, SO, SF and occasionally others) and it really isn't a problem.

If a post is better suited to one of the others, the community migrates it. You'll learn from that for next time. Yes, you could ask on the meta first if you are really unsure, but communities here are pretty supportive and will vote to migrate, or flag for a mod to migrate.

Comment: My question is about topics that are on-topic on multiple SE sites, sort of the opposite of migration.

Comment: Exactly - don't worry about it. Ask the question and we'll migrate if needed.

Comment: My point is that some questions are on-topic for *multiple* SE sites. If a question fits well on, say, two sites, if the question is on-topic for both of them, what is the use of migrating the question between those sites?

Comment: You don't migrate it. It's fine. That's why I'm saying don't worry about it. I'd it is better suited elsewhere will get migrated, if not then it won't.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep the question where it was. Since it's on-topic on a second site too, I'll lose out on the expertise of the second site's users, and remember, crossposting isn't allowed, so I'm stuck with posting my question on one site only. What do you think should be done in a situation like this?